# Adding Map items to Map variable in model

Tags: flutter, dictionary, dart

I am creating a new model class in my Flutter project:

```
class Training {
  var dataPackage;
  String objetivo;
  int duracion;
  Map<String,String> sesiones;


  Training({
    this.dataPackage,
    this.objetivo,
    this.duracion,
    this.sesiones,
  });
}
```

I would like to create some hardcoded items as follows:

```
 List trainings = <Training>[
      Training(
        dataPackage: null,
        objetivo: "Pérdida de peso",
        duracion: 4,
        sesiones: {'num_sesion': 'Sesión 1', "nombre_sesion": "Cardio-Abductor-Biceps"}
      )
    ]
```

In this first item the variable sesiones has only one Map object, but I would like to add more than one Map objets.

Which is the correct way to add more objects like

```
{'num_sesion': 'Sesión 2', "nombre_sesion": "Cardio"}

{'num_sesion': 'Sesión 3', "nombre_sesion": "Abductor-Biceps"}

{'num_sesion': 'Sesión 4', "nombre_sesion": "Triceps"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to store those fields as array not as map

```
class Training {
  var dataPackage;
  String objetivo;
  int duracion;
  List sesiones;


  Training({
    this.dataPackage,
    this.objetivo,
    this.duracion,
    this.sesiones,
  });
}
```

Then you can pass the variable to model.

```
List at = [{'num_sesion': 'Sesión 2', "nombre_sesion": "Cardio"}

{'num_sesion': 'Sesión 3', "nombre_sesion": "Abductor-Biceps"}

{'num_sesion': 'Sesión 4', "nombre_sesion": "Triceps"}];

  Training(
        dataPackage: null,
        objetivo: "Pérdida de peso",
        duracion: 4,
        sesiones: at
      );
```

Add more maps ;

```
List atx = training["sesiones"];
atx.add(yournewmap);
training["sesiones"] = atx;
```

Also it should work;

```
training["sesiones"].add(newMap);
```

If you want to add multiple maps, you need to add only iteration.

Comment: And the model remains as it is now?

Comment: I have added how to append your list in the model. Update your model sesiones as List .

Comment: Would you mind to show me the complete new model and  a complete item to the model class, to get it clear?